# Apply width to all tags of a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new to JavaScript and jquery. I have some Kendo DropDownList that I need to set the list itself to auto expand to the width of the lengthiest item. I have been able to do this per control via the following code:

```
var dropdownlist = $("#Offeror").data("kendoDropDownList");
dropdownlist.list.css("min-width", $("#Offeror").parent().width());
dropdownlist.list.width("auto");

dropdownlist = $("#ReqCertlevel").data("kendoDropDownList");
dropdownlist.list.css("min-width", $("#ReqCertlevel").parent().width()-6);
dropdownlist.list.width("auto");
```

The above code works, but I have to set it via each ID. I have several drop down boxes. So, I would rather set the width of all tags with the `DD_List` class. I tried the following:

```
$( ".DD_List" ).each(function( index, object ) {
    var dropdownlist = object.data("kendoDropDownList");
    dropdownlist.list.css("min-width", object.parent().width());
    dropdownlist.list.width("auto");
});
```

It is not working. What am I doing wrong? I am open to a CSS solution as well.

**Edit:**

Basically I am trying to turn:

[image]

Into:

[image]

Here is the code in the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Offeror, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @(
            Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width: 125px;", @class = "DD_List" })
                .Name("Offeror")
                .SelectedIndex((int)Model.Offeror)
                .BindTo(Enum.GetNames(typeof(EnumQuoteOfferor)).ToList())
        )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Offeror, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

When the page is rendered in the browser, here is what the view source has for that control:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Offeror">Offeror</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="DD_List" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Offeror field is required." id="Offeror" name="Offeror" style="width: 125px;" type="text" />
        <script>
            jQuery(function () { jQuery("#Offeror").kendoDropDownList({ "dataSource": ["AmptechInc", "AmptechEnergySystemsInc", "AmptechTechnicalServicesInc"], "index": 0 }); });
        </script>
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Offeror" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would use CSS for this purpose, not JavaScript.

Comment: I agree with @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: **@MikeMcCaughan** and **@Rick Sibley** That would be great. How would I go about doing that given the above code?

Answer (score 0):

The wrong lines are:

```
var dropdownlist = object.data("kendoDropDownList");
dropdownlist.list.css("min-width", object.parent().width());
```

This because [jQuery#each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) has two arguments, the second one is a dom element and not a jQuery element.

So, change to:

```
$( ".DD_List" ).each(function( index, ele) {
    var dropdownlist = $(ele).data("kendoDropDownList");
    dropdownlist.list.css("min-width", $(ele).parent().width());
    dropdownlist.list.width("auto");
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it isn't working. I have added some more information in my question that may help.

Comment: @Linger The only problem I may figure out is: when you call the .each(...? If your "...$("#Offeror").data..." work the fixed each should work. I'm sorry but I cannot test it.

Comment: Did you take a look to [open event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#events-open)?